# random number generator with Generalized pareto distribution and Weilbull distribution in VBA

Tags: excel, random, distribution, weibull, vba

I'd like to generate random numbers with Weibull and generalised pareto distributions in VBA. Could you please help me with it. I'm not interested to use Analysis Toolpack-VBA.

Thanks in advance,
Skeihani

Answer (score 0):

These user-defined functions may do what you want:

```
Function RandWeib(fScale As Single, _
                  fShape As Single, _
                  Optional bVolatile As Boolean = False) As Single

  ' shg 2008
  ' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution

  ' Returns a random variate with Weibull distribution
  ' fScale > 0
  ' fShape > 0
  ' By formula: =Scale * -LN(RAND()) ^ (1 / Shape)

  If bVolatile Then Application.Volatile

  RandWeib = fScale * (-Log(1! - Rnd())) ^ (1! / fShape)
End Function

Function RandPareto(fScale As Single, _
                    fShape As Single, _
                    Optional bVolatile As Boolean = False) As Single
  ' shg 2015
  ' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

  ' Returns a random variate with Pareto distribution
  ' fScale > 0
  ' fShape > 0
  ' By formula: =Scale / RAND() ^ (1 / Shape)

  If bVolatile Then Application.Volatile

  RandPareto = fScale / (1! - Rnd()) ^ (1! / fShape)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you shg, do you have anything for Weibull distribution as well.

Comment: oh sorry, just noticed there is RandWeib for Weibull distribution, Thanks